# How to fill area with custom color under line in nvd3 linechart ?

Tags: css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm working with nvd3 and I'm not much hands-on with its styling (css properties) to customize it. I have a line chart with two data lines on it.
The code for drawing the lines is following:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart();

        chart.margin({
            left : 100,
            bottom : 100
        }).useInteractiveGuideline(true).showLegend(true).duration(250);
        chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Date").tickFormat(function(d) {
            var date = new Date(d);
            return d3.time.format("%b-%e")(date);
        });
        chart.yAxis.axisLabel('').tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

        chart.showXAxis(true);

        d3.select('#startupRiskLineChart').datum(
                prepareDataObj(val1_y, val1_x, val2_y, val1_x))
                .transition().call(chart);
        ;
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
            nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
        });
        return chart;
    });
```

Is there any way to fill the area under data line with a lighter color? 
Any help would be highy apperiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a line chart with a filled area in a specific color:

- Add `area: true` to the data series, as in [this example](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html).
- Add this CSS: `.nv-area { fill: red }`

The opacity of the area is set to 0.5, so filling it with red will actually make it pink:

[image: Graph with pink area under the line]

Comment: You can also play with fill-opacity if you don't like the default.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.color(["red","yellow","blue"]);
```

> '#00FFFF','#0FF','cyan' all are valid ways to set colors

Another way is set it in data itself

```
    [{
      values:[{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:9},{x:4,y:16}],
      key: 'not a Sine Wave',
      color: '#ff7f0e'  //color - optional: choose your own line color.
    }]
```

**duplicate question i guess**

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
classed: "my-custom-approx-line"
```

to config of specific line and add styling:

```
&.nv-area {
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of commit `#becd772`

Use `.nv-group{ fill-opacity: 1.0 !important; }` to fill the area with the same color as the line